# Couldn't find sitename 'shell' in sitecore.config in 9.3 for lang fall back

Tags: language-fallback

I don't see site name shell in version 9.3, but to enable language fall back as per Sitecore documentation we need to add the

'enableItemLanguageFallback' and 'enableFieldLanguageFallback' in shell site.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/enable-and-set-up-language-fallback.html

Do we need to manually include this in the patch file?

```
<sites>
      <site name="shell">
        <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
</sites>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore shell site is defined inside the file : **\App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Sites.config**

[image]

To verify if the **shell site** is defined on your sites definition , you can check using
**yourhostnane/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx**

Answer (score 2):

As @vlad is saying you can find the `shell` site in `\App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Sites.config`.

And yes, create a separate patch file to have these language-specific changes, as this is `Sitecore best practice to not change in any OOTB config file` but create a separate patch file like below.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="shell">
        <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
      <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
      </site>
   </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And after applying these changes, make sure to run showconfig page - **yourhostnane/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx** and verify your latest changes.